# Change Charset to UTF-8

Tags: vba, utf-8, outlook

So I have this script which works awesome, but I need one extra option.
I have a rule for incoming mail with a specific subject, and it uses the script below. Is it possible when it exports it to .msg to use utf-8?

```
Sub MySubroutineName(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    MessageAndAttachmentProcessor Item, , True, , , , True
End Sub
```

Above is a subroutine to the actual script.

```
Public Declare Function GetProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetProfileStringA" _
    (ByVal lpAppName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
    ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, _
    ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
  Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
  ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
  ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub MessageAndAttachmentProcessor(Item As Outlook.MailItem, _
Optional bolPrintMsg As Boolean, _
Optional bolSaveMsg As Boolean, _
Optional bolPrintAtt As Boolean, _
Optional bolSaveAtt As Boolean, _
Optional bolInsertLink As Boolean, _
Optional strAttFileTypes As String, _
Optional strFolderPath As String, _
Optional varMsgFormat As OlSaveAsType, _
Optional strPrinter As String)

Dim olkAttachment As Outlook.Attachment, _
    objFSO As Object, _
    strMyPath As String, _
    strExtension As String, _
    strFileName As String, _
    strOriginalPrinter As String, _
    strLinkText As String, _
    strRootFolder As String, _
    strTempFolder As String, _
    varFileType As Variant, _
    intCount As Integer, _
    intIndex As Integer, _
    arrFileTypes As Variant

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempFolder = Environ("TEMP") & "\"

If strAttFileTypes = "" Then
    arrFileTypes = Array("*")
Else
    arrFileTypes = Split(strAttFileTypes, ",")
End If

If bolPrintMsg Or bolPrintAtt Then
    If strPrinter <> "" Then
        strOriginalPrinter = GetDefaultPrinter()
        SetDefaultPrinter strPrinter
    End If
End If

If bolSaveMsg Or bolSaveAtt Then
    If strFolderPath = "" Then
        strRootFolder = "S:\mail\"
    Else
        strRootFolder = strFolderPath & IIf(Right(strFolderPath, 1) = "\", "", "\")
    End If
End If

If bolSaveMsg Then
    Select Case varMsgFormat
        Case olHTML
            strExtension = ".HTML"
        Case olMSG
            strExtension = ".MSG"
        Case olRTF
            strExtension = ".RTF"
        Case olDoc
            strExtension = ".DOC"
        Case olTXT
            strExtension = ".TXT"
        Case Else
            strExtension = ".MSG"
    End Select
    Item.SaveAs strRootFolder & RemoveIllegalCharacters(Item.Subject) & strExtension, varMsgFormat
End If

For intIndex = Item.Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set olkAttachment = Item.Attachments.Item(intIndex)
    'Print the attachments if requested'
    If bolPrintAtt Then
        If olkAttachment.Type <> olEmbeddeditem Then
            For Each strFileType In arrFileTypes
                If (strFileType = "*") Or (LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(olkAttachment.FileName)) = LCase(strFileType)) Then
                    olkAttachment.SaveAsFile strTempFolder & olkAttachment.FileName
                    ShellExecute 0&, "print", strTempFolder & olkAttachment.FileName, 0&, 0&, 0&
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
    'Save the attachments if requested'
    If bolSaveAtt Then
        strFileName = olkAttachment.FileName
        intCount = 0
        Do While True
            strMyPath = strRootFolder & strFileName
            If objFSO.FileExists(strMyPath) Then
                intCount = intCount + 1
                strFileName = "Copy (" & intCount & ") of " & olkAttachment.FileName
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        olkAttachment.SaveAsFile strMyPath
        If bolInsertLink Then
            If Item.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
                strLinkText = strLinkText & "<a href=""file://" & strMyPath & """>" & olkAttachment.FileName & "</a><br>"
            Else
                strLinkText = strLinkText & strMyPath & vbCrLf
            End If
            olkAttachment.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next

If bolPrintMsg Then
    Item.PrintOut
End If

If bolPrintMsg Or bolPrintAtt Then
    If strOriginalPrinter <> "" Then
        SetDefaultPrinter strOriginalPrinter
    End If
End If

If bolInsertLink Then
    If Item.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
        Item.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody & "<br><br>Removed Attachments<br><br>" & strLinkText
    Else
        Item.Body = Item.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Removed Attachments" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strLinkText
    End If
    Item.Save
End If

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set olkAttachment = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetDefaultPrinter() As String
Dim strPrinter As String, _
    intReturn As Integer
strPrinter = Space(255)
intReturn = GetProfileString("Windows", ByVal "device", "", strPrinter, Len(strPrinter))
If intReturn Then
    strPrinter = UCase(Left(strPrinter, InStr(strPrinter, ",") - 1))
End If
GetDefaultPrinter = strPrinter
End Function

Function RemoveIllegalCharacters(strValue As String) As String
' Purpose: Remove characters that cannot be in a filename from a string.'
' Written: 4/24/2009'
' Author:  BlueDevilFan'
' Outlook: All versions'
RemoveIllegalCharacters = strValue
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "<", "")
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, ">", "")
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, ":", "")
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, Chr(34), "'")
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "/", "")
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "\", "")
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "|", "")
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "?", "")
RemoveIllegalCharacters = Replace(RemoveIllegalCharacters, "*", "")
End Function

Sub SetDefaultPrinter(strPrinterName As String)
Dim objNet As Object
Set objNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
objNet.SetDefaultPrinter strPrinterName
Set objNet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use olMsgUnicode format, not olMsg.